# regular expression to match all except the last 2 strings in every line <python>

Tags: regex

Here's my data to play around with.

```
The quick 12 apple
brown8 fox jumped 67 banana
sam 20 ace over 2.5 orange
the13 lazy dog 88.09 grapes
```

The data is consistent, there's always a number and a word that follows(ex. 12 apple) at the end of every line. I would like an output to be something like : The quick, brown8 fox jumped, sam 20 ace over, the13 lazy dog

Comment: Are you using Pandas? Have you tried any pattern yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following Regex:

```
/(?: (?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?) \w+\s?)/g
```

Then you need to `replace` the matches with an `empty string`.

That should give you: '*The quick, brown8 fox jumped, over, the13 lazy dog*'.

The regex use noncapturing Groups (start with `(?:` ) and starts by matching a Space, then one or more numbers ('`\d`'), an optional decimal point ('`\.`') followed by one or more digits ('`\d+`'). Then another Space and finally one or more Word characters and an optional White space.
The global flag should give all results, which must be replaced.

**Edit**:

Seems you want a comma (,) where the matches are, so you should replace with comma instead.

**Edit2**:
According to new info:

```
/(?: (?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?) \w+$)/gm
```

You now have to specify multiline option.

Comment: Thanks Poul! Your answer is partially correct and I apologize I haven't been really very precise with my sample data. supposed there's another instance of the pattern before the end of the line say for example (sam 10 ace over 2.4 orange). Your regex will match both 10 ace and 2.4  orange. I would like just the last 2 strings so the ideal output would match 2.4 orange only before I replace the match with empty string. Did I make sense? sorry for that.